# E(max) of something

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Let Z ∼ N (0, 1), and c be a nonnegative constant. Find E(max(Z − c, 0)), in
terms of the standard Normal CDF Φ and PDF ϕ. (This kind of calculation often comes
up in quantitative finance.)

Hint: Use LOTUS, and handle the max symbol by adjusting the limits of integration
appropriately. As a check, make sure that your answer reduces to 1/
√
2π when c = 0;
this must be the case since we show in Chapter 7 that E|Z| =
p
2/π, and we have |Z| =
max(Z, 0) + max(−Z, 0) so by symmetry
E|Z| = E(max(Z, 0)) + E(max(−Z, 0)) = 2E(max(Z, 0)).

I wasn't sure how to start with the maximum bit.

Comment: Can you tell me what the Law of the unconscious statistician is?

Comment: A maximum function is just a piecewise function. So you split the integral for $Z > c$ and $Z < c$ accordingly.

Comment: Essentially the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971814/question-involving-expectation-and-standard-normal-cdf though asked five hours earlier